# Get information from tagGroup

Tags: dm-script

all:

I tried to use tagGroup to save flags and parameters. When I tried to read them by using TagGroupGetTagAsBoolean(tag_path, value), it will return nothing if the tag_path doesn't exist. Then the value will still be the value during initialization, aka, 0. How can I know whether the tag_path is exist?

Maybe there is some command to check the existence of tag_path. But I have a lot of tags need to be read. So I'd like to find a better way.

```
String config_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Gatan\\Plugins\\config.gtg"

TagGroup ui_config_tg = NewTagGroup()
ui_config_tg.TagGroupLoadFromFile(config_path)
Number jpg_flag
ui_config_tg.TagGroupGetTagAsBoolean("flag:jpg_flag", jpg_flag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation, you may notice that every function of the form TagGroupGetTagAsXXX returns a Boolean value. It is this returned boolean that tells you whether the function was able to find the tagged value and return it successfully. In other words, if the specified tag path does not exist, then the function will return false, otherwise it returns true. So a better way to implement your sample code would be as follows:

```
String config_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Gatan\\Plugins\\config.gtg"
TagGroup ui_config_tg = NewTagGroup()
ui_config_tg.TagGroupLoadFromFile(config_path)
Number jpg_flag
Number tagIsValid = ui_config_tg.TagGroupGetTagAsBoolean("flag:jpg_flag", jpg_flag)
if (!tagIsValid)
{
    // Insert code here to initialize jpg_flag with a default value
    // You may also wish to set this default value at the missing tag
    // path through the use of the TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean function.
}
```